# Sonar lines of code vs. sloccount

Tags: sonarqube

We're just switching our metrics gathering to sonar.  We previously used sloccount to get the lines of code and are now using sonar but the counts are coming up as around 40% different. Does anyone know what the differences are and if there is any configuration that I should do in sonar to align the two?

Comment: There should not be such a difference as the definition for a line of code is pretty simple: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions#Metricdefinitions-Size. Could you please provide some examples on files with big differences?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on Stack Overflow. See ["Are taglines & signatures disallowed?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed) and ["Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I think that this is probably because my configuration of sonar.sources is not correct, so that sonar is not actually analysing all of my code.  As David says, the SLOC counts on individual files are usually the same with Sonar and SLOCCount.

Answer (score 2):

On sonar side this is pretty simple : each line containing a character which is neither a blank character or a character part of a comment is considered to be part of a line of code and there is no way to tune this behavior.